# How do I get the remote tracking branch for a branch in Git?

Tags: git

For example, let's say `master` is tracking `origin/master`.  How can I ask Git to tell me that `master` is tracking `origin/master` in a way useful for programs?

```
<fill-in-the-blank> master
```

Comment: Apparently all I needed was `@{u}`.  Thanks @AndrewC!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing this in a script the best way is to call into the config

```
git config --get branch.${BRANCH}.remote
git config --get branch.${BRANCH}.merge
```

If you are only interested in the currently checked out branch then git provides the special reference `@{u}` to refer to the current upstream.  Just use `rev-parse` to make sure it's valid before using it.

If you were just typing at the terminal then `git branch -vv` is the way to go

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have so far.  Is there a better way to turn that from `ref/heads/blah` to `blah` other than doing a search and replace?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
git branch -vv
```

which returns an output like

```
* master 5a24820 [origin/master]  commitmsg
```

If you're running shell scripts and you just want the remote branch:

```
git branch -vv | grep -oP '\[.+\]'
```

You could also use the following command:

`git remote show origin`

which displays information for your remote origin repository.

e.g:

```
Remote branch:
  master tracked   Local branch configured for 'git pull':
  master merges with remote master
```

The `master merges with remote master` tells you that `origin\master` is being tracked by your master branch. It's not very elegant though.

Comment: That returns a lot of things and I don't know that master is tracking origin.

Comment: Doesn't it say `Remote branch: master tracked` ?

Comment: It says [this](https://gist.github.com/schwern/1f92cb08577623ccbc0e).  Also *I cannot assume master is tracking origin*.  There can be many remotes.

Comment: I added another way: `git branch -vv` - This seems closest to what you need?

Comment: It's closer, but I'd need to do a lot of parsing of ugly output which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I suggested a pipe to grep which can help. I don't think there's a command closer to what you need I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Mike - relying on`git branch` in scripts is discouraged.  See http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/06/checking-current-branch-programatically.html